# What is the use of "attribute" attribute of action node in struts-config.xml?

Tags: java, dtd, struts-1, struts-config

From the dtd definition of Struts-Config.xml
http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-core/dtddoc/index.html

The `action` element describes an `ActionMapping object` that is to be used to process a request for a specific `module-relative URI`. 


The following attributes are defined :
`attribute` name of the `request-scope` or `session-scope` attribute that is used to access our ActionForm bean, if it is other than the bean's specified `name`. 
Optional if `name` is specified, else not valid.

I am confuse between the `scope` attribute and `attribute` attribute. 

Where i can use `attribute` attribute ? 


Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its same as plain `request.setAttribute(obj , obj);` or `session.setAttribute(obj,obj)`

It is used to display data on the view typically jsp using jstl or other struts specific taglibs